# how to sent current directory path(Space in the path) into terminal via xcode application

Tags: xcode, node.js, appium

I have to run a script from Objective C code. my script **server.js** is located at the path

**/Users/SS/Desktop/iPhone App/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/server.js**

In objective c code, I set the path as

[self.serverTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"/Users/SS/Desktop/iPhone App/Appium.app/Contents/Resources", @"node_modules/appium"]];

launch path with argument

[self.serverTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[self.serverTask setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-l", @"-c", nodeCommandString, nil]];

The problem I am facing is that when I am running XCode application, it is receiving only the path before the space (i.e. **/Users/SS/Desktop/iPhone**) and through an error

**/bin/bash: /Users/SS/Desktop/ab: No such file or directory**

Is there is an idea by which I can access path after the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send the path of your appium inside double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Change your path like this./

```
[self.serverTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"/Users/SS/Desktop/iPhone\ App/Appium.app/Contents/Resources", @"node_modules/appium"]];
```

Add `\` before the space.

Answer (score 1):

Send the path of your appium inside double quotes like following.

```
[self.serverTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"/Users/SS/Desktop/iPhone\ App/Appium.app/Contents/Resources", @"node_modules/appium"]];
```